# Google Sheets App Script If Else not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Test1** Sheet

[image]

**Test2** Sheet

[image]

I want to compare **News01** from **Test1 A Column** with **Test2 A Column**, and need to fetch the corresponding **Test2 B column** value

So the result should be **Finance** in **Sheet1 B column**

But If I use else, even when if statement is true it's going to else statement.
If I delete else statement, then if statement is working.

I don't know why when if statement is true, it's going to else statement by default

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Test1");
  var target_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Test2");
  var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = source_sheet.getRange('A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var days = target_sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat();
  var codes = target_sheet.getRange('B1:B').getValues().flat();

  inputs.forEach(function(input, count){
    for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
      if(days[i].trim() == input.trim()){
        source_sheet.getRange('B' + (count + source_sheet.getLastRow())).setValue(codes[i]);
        Logger.log(codes[i]);
        break;
      }
      else{
        Logger.log("News not found")
      }
    
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But If I use else, even when if statement is true it's going to else statement.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: If statement is true in the script I attached in the question.
So my output should be **Finance**
But when I run the script, I get **News not found** from else statement.

So, I don't know, when if statement is true, it should go inside if statement. But it's going to else statement.

If I remove else statement, then If statement is working as expected.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample input situations, I think that when your script is run, `days[i].trim() == input.trim()` is `false` at the 1st loop. And, at the 2nd loop, `days[i].trim() == input.trim()` is `true`. By this, the script of `setValue` is run. How about this flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logging `News not found` for each comparisons with all the rows of `Test2`, which is improper.

Instead, you should only log when the comparison is finished.

```js
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Test1");
  var target_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Test2");
  var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = source_sheet.getRange('A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var days = target_sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat();
  var codes = target_sheet.getRange('B1:B').getValues().flat();

  inputs.forEach(function(input, count){
    let found = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
      if(days[i].trim() == input.trim()){
        source_sheet.getRange('B' + (count + source_sheet.getLastRow())).setValue(codes[i]);
        Logger.log(codes[i]);
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) { Logger.log("News not found"); }
  });
}
```

Or simply,

```js
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Test1");
  var target_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Test2");
  var lastRow = source_sheet.getLastRow();
  var inputs = source_sheet.getRange('A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var days = target_sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat();
  var codes = target_sheet.getRange('B1:B').getValues().flat();

  inputs.forEach(function(input, count){
    for(var i = 0; i < days.length; i++){
      if(days[i].trim() == input.trim()){
        source_sheet.getRange('B' + (count + source_sheet.getLastRow())).setValue(codes[i]);
        Logger.log(codes[i]);
        return;
      }
    }
    Logger.log("News not found");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = sh1.getLastRow();
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().map(e => e.trim());
  var vs2 = sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  vs2.forEach(r => {
    if(~vs1.indexOf(r[0].trim())) {
       Logger.log(r[1]);
    }
  });
}
```